# PHP- print binary into array

Tags: php, arrays, binary

I have printed out this binary but yet to be stored in an array.

```html
<?php
// get contents of a file into a string
$filename = "rock.wav";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));


for($i = 0; $i < strlen($contents); $i++) {
    $char = $contents[$i];

    $str = ord ($char);
 echo str_pad(decbin($str), 8,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."<br/>";
```

The outcome is this:

```
01010010
01001001
01000110
01000110
00000010
```

it has more likely ten thousand line.

I want to read them into array that looks like this,

```
[0] = '0';
[1] = '1';
[2] = '0';
[3] = '1';
[4] = '0';
[5] = '0';
[6] = '1';
[7] = '0';

[0] = '0';
[1] = '1';
[2] = '0';
[3] = '0';
[4] = '1';
[5] = '0';
[6] = '0';
[7] = '1';
```

Any clues of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [];
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($contents); $i++) {
   $char = $contents[$i];

   $str = ord ($char);
   echo "<pre>";
   $array[] = str_split('',str_pad(decbin($str), 8,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT));
}
var_dump($array);
```

this should work

Comment: Thanks for your comment! but it shows 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' 
at print_r = explode

Comment: @hizz because it should be variable like $print_r = ... add dollar sign and it will work

Comment: @hizz edited. sorry answered it in a hurry. test now it should work

Comment: it is showing error which is unexpected ';'
i already test by using $print_r =
 also displaying the same error

Comment: @hizz try now. only single closing bracket was not working you should be able to figure it out by reading the error.

Comment: the problem is i can't figure out what to adjust by referring to the error since it just state  unexpected ';' . i don't know why it shows the error.

Comment: still showing error about the usage of explode, but never mind, i think i ask the wrong question, the output that i want is arr[0] = 0000011010101101
arr[1] = 0000000010101101

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_split`

```
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($contents); $i++) {
    $char = $contents[$i];

    $str = ord ($char);
    $binArray = str_split(str_pad(decbin($str), 8,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT));
    print_r($binArray);    
}
```

Comment: it works just fine for me. But it wont go in a list of line.. it just print in one line only

Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 1 [7] => 0 )

Comment: You can add ```echo '<br/>';``` after ```print_r```

Comment: ouh sorry the error is for putting '<br/>'; at the end of $binArray, now it shown perfectly.
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 )  . Thanks a lot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50324622/php-2-bytes-into-1-array?noredirect=1#comment87665456_50324622 this is my actual question. Since, it could help others too, i just remain this question here.