# PHP- 2 bytes into 1 array

Tags: php, arrays, wav, steganography

I have printed out this binary which is 8 per line but yet to be stored in an array.

```
    <?php
// get contents of a file into a string
$filename = "rock.wav";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));


for($i = 0; $i < strlen($contents); $i++) {
    $char = $contents[$i];

    $str = ord ($char);

    echo str_pad(decbin($str), 8,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."<br/>";    


}
?>
```

The outcome is this:

```
01010010
01001001
01000110
01000110
00000010
```

it actually has more likely ten thousand line.

I want to read them into array which is looking like this,

```
arr[0] = 0000011010101101
arr[1] = 0000000010101101
arr[2] = 0000011010101101
arr[3] = 0000000010101101
arr[4] = 0000011010101101
arr[5] = 0000000010101101
arr[6] = 0000000010101101
arr[7] = 0000011010101101
arr[8] = 0000000010101101
arr[9] = 0000011010101101
```

which means, i want to store 2 bytes in 1 array, so that i can subtitute new bit into the last bit of the byte.

Any ways to do this? Do i need to use loop?

Comment: Do you need to create the data in binary or are you just trying to achieve 'so that i can substitute new bit into the last bit of the byte'.

Comment: @hizz Please check my answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any algorithm behind "2 bytes in 1 array", like concatenating them?

Comment: @NigelRen i have the binary data like the outcome above. but it did not stored into array yet. so how to store 2 bytes into 1 array. ignore the substitution.

Comment: It's unclear how you go from the printed values to the 2-bytes-per-array-element in the following example. But if you want to combine 2 sequential bytes from your stream, why not bitshift the first by 8, e.g., `(byte1 << 8) + byte2`? And if all you want to do is change the lsb of 1 out of every 2 bytes, why not do exactly that?

Comment: i have tried array_chunk, but error **array_chunk() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given** always appear @NicoHaase

Comment: @Reti43 since later on i want to read array 15 only(last bit), i think better do it in array, not just simple combination.and  i do not familiarize with bitshift. alright i need to discover that first.

Comment: I'm suspecting an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) here. If you're doing steganography, you want to read in the byte array, make whatever modifications you want and write that back to a new file. Combining 2 bytes at a time in a new array isn't conductive towards that end. You can simply modify the lsb of every second byte by modifying your loop to `for($i = 0; $i < strlen($contents); $i = $i + 2)`. You should also be careful to not modify the file [header](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) and render the file unreadable.